# Age in hours calculator

Tags: python, datetime, calculator, qt

I've written a small script, which calculates hours since the birth. I ask use about how old they are in years, months and day. I show them approximately how many hours they have lived. Below is the code.

Please tell me how can I improve it, in terms of algorithms, time/date calculation, UX, and python best practices.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

"""
File: ageinhours.py
Author: Santosh Kumar
Github: @santosh
Description: Calculate age in hours.
"""

import sys
try:
    from PySide import QtGui, QtCore
except ModuleNotFoundError:
    from PySide2.QtWidgets import QtGui
    from PySide2 import QtCore

class AgeInHours(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    """The main window of AgeInHours"""
    def __init__(self):
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Age in Hours")
        self.setGeometry(200, 200, 350, 150)
#         self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon("favicon.png"))
        self.initUi()

    def initUi(self):
        self.centralWidget = QtGui.QWidget(self)
        lyt_central = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self.centralWidget)

        lbl_instructions = QtGui.QLabel("How much time has passed \
since your birth?")

        lyt_year = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        lbl_year = QtGui.QLabel("Year:    ")
        self.slr_year = QtGui.QSlider(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.slr_year.setMinimum(0)
        self.slr_year.setMaximum(25)
        self.slr_year.setValue(21)
        self.slr_year.setTickPosition(QtGui.QSlider.TicksBelow)
        self.slr_year.setTickInterval(1)
        self.slr_year.valueChanged.connect(self.year_change)
        self.slr_year.valueChanged.connect(self.calculate_hours)
        self.led_year = QtGui.QLineEdit()
        self.led_year.returnPressed.connect(
                lambda: self.slr_year.setValue(int(self.led_year.text())))
        self.led_year.setFixedWidth(55)
        lyt_year.addWidget(lbl_year)
        lyt_year.addWidget(self.slr_year)
        lyt_year.addWidget(self.led_year)

        lyt_month = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        lbl_month = QtGui.QLabel("Month: ")
        self.slr_month = QtGui.QSlider(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.slr_month.setMinimum(0)
        self.slr_month.setMaximum(12)
        self.slr_month.setValue(8)
        self.slr_month.setTickPosition(QtGui.QSlider.TicksBelow)
        self.slr_month.setTickInterval(1)
        self.slr_month.valueChanged.connect(self.month_change)
        self.slr_month.valueChanged.connect(self.calculate_hours)
        self.led_month = QtGui.QLineEdit()
        self.led_month.returnPressed.connect(
                lambda: self.slr_month.setValue(int(self.led_month.text())))
        self.led_month.setFixedWidth(55)
        lyt_month.addWidget(lbl_month)
        lyt_month.addWidget(self.slr_month)
        lyt_month.addWidget(self.led_month)

        lyt_day = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        lbl_day = QtGui.QLabel("Day:     ")  # extra spaces to match alignment
        self.slr_day = QtGui.QSlider(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.slr_day.setMinimum(0)
        self.slr_day.setMaximum(31)
        self.slr_day.setValue(7)
        self.slr_day.setTickPosition(QtGui.QSlider.TicksBelow)
        self.slr_day.setTickInterval(1)
        self.slr_day.valueChanged.connect(self.day_change)
        self.slr_day.valueChanged.connect(self.calculate_hours)
        self.led_day = QtGui.QLineEdit()
        self.led_day.returnPressed.connect(
                lambda: self.slr_day.setValue(int(self.led_day.text())))
        self.led_day.setFixedWidth(55)
        lyt_day.addWidget(lbl_day)
        lyt_day.addWidget(self.slr_day)
        lyt_day.addWidget(self.led_day)

        lyt_output = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        lbl_output = QtGui.QLabel("Your age in hours is approximately: ")
        self.lbl_output_data = QtGui.QLabel()
        lyt_output.addWidget(lbl_output)
        lyt_output.addWidget(self.lbl_output_data)

        lyt_central.addWidget(lbl_instructions)
        lyt_central.addLayout(lyt_year)
        lyt_central.addLayout(lyt_month)
        lyt_central.addLayout(lyt_day)
        lyt_central.addLayout(lyt_output)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)

    def year_change(self, value):
        self.led_year.setText(str(value))

    def month_change(self, value):
        self.led_month.setText(str(value))

    def day_change(self, value):
        self.led_day.setText(str(value))

    def calculate_hours(self):
        """Get years, months and days and update the age."""
        year = int(self.slr_year.value())
        month = int(self.slr_month.value())
        day = int(self.slr_day.value())

        final_output = (year * 365.25 * 24) + (month * 30 * 24) + (day * 24)

        self.lbl_output_data.setText(str(final_output))


    def keyPressEvent(self, e):
        """Response to keypresses."""
        if e.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Escape:
            self.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = AgeInHours()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you're manually trying to calculate the amount of hours since birth, which will be difficult because of leap years and the general difficulty of working with dates. I would recommend using the `datetime` module instead:

```
from datetime import datetime
current_time = datetime.now()
# Use the information you collect in your GUI to enter a datetime for birth; call this variable birth_time
time_diff = current_time - birth_time
hours = round(time_diff.total_seconds() / 3600)
```

Comment: That's something new I learnt today. Anything else you would suggest?

Comment: When working with dates and times, I follow the advice of Tom Scott in this Computerphile video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-5wpm-gesOY. The advice is simple: when working with dates and times, always use your language's built-in libraries. Never try to use your own date/time modules, because you will somehow mess up and/or have a huge headache from working with all the edge cases.